# Parse and Swift: Push notifications with "aps": {"content-available": 1} not being received by didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I making a Parse REST API request like this

```
  curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: key-here" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: key-here" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "where": {
          "deviceToken": "token-here",
          "deviceType": "ios"
        },
        "data": {
          "aps": {"content-available": "1"}
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

Now, this gets read by the device, when the app is turned on. But when i lock the device and the make the above curl request again, nothing happens. Below is my `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    println("received notification")
    var remoteServer = RemoteServer()
    remoteServer.sendDataToServer { (success) -> () in
         completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
    }
}
```

As soon as I, open the app the inside call of `didReceiveRemoteNotification` gets excuted. but again, nothing happens when the app is not open or phone is locked.

Any idea/suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you configure all the certificates and provisioning profile correctly. because as you said you are receiving the Response when app is in Active state (in your words its Turned on)

But when app is in background mode or when you lock the device at that time your app's status is not active. and you are not receiving the Alerts or Sound for push notification.

This happens because of PAYLOAD which contains information about how the system will alert the user OR handle the data you sent.

for each notification, you need to compose a JSON dictionary object which contain another directory named **"aps"**

**aps** contain following :

1. An alert message (which will displayed to user) **[String OR
   Dictionary]**
2. A number to badge (it is displayed on the top right corner of App icon.) **[number]**
3. A sound to play (it plays the sound) **[String] here you need to pass the name of sound file in app bundle**

If you want to show the alert or banner on your device Notification Panel or on the lock screen, then your **aps** must have the proper values according to their types.

And one more thing

```
"aps": {"content-available": "1"}
```

your **aps** contain the above JSON.

> **content-available** This property with value **1** Means : Remote notification work as **SILENT NOTIFICATION** And when **SILENT
>   NOTIFICATION** kind of notification arrives iOS activce your app in
>   background mode from which you can complete you background progress.
>   (For ex : Downloading the data or other process)

here i provide the sample example of **aps** dictionary.

A **aps** JSON example which include "alert, sound and badge" ia as below :

```
    "aps" : {

    "alert" : "This a alert",

    "badge" : 1,

    "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"

}
```

And make sure you have configure for the remote-notifcation correctly in your AppDelegate class.

For iOS7 and older (in swift)

```
        var types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
```

For iOS8

```
        var notiType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert

        var notiSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings
        notiSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes:notiType, categories: nil)

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notiSettings)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Hope It helps.

Comment: yes I am passing the same json set. Although, when I send an alert with sound. The same is reaching just fine. But the ```didReceiveRemoteNotification``` is never getting called when the app isn't active.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification method will be called when push notification arrives in app active state.

Comment: if your app is in UIApplicationStateBackground or UIApplicationStateInactive and the user opened a push notification from the notification center then didReceiveRemoteNotification will be called.

Comment: but according to the documentation it should be called in the bg right? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:

Comment: AS per iOS8 documentation Read This may be this helps :

Comment: application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a push notification arrives.

Comment: However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Comment: right I read the same but the user has not force quit it. It performs normally that is enters the background then the foreground.